# Can't upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz

Tags: apt, upgrade

I get this error when trying to upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
E: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz
  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 9):

you need to remove all the content of `/var/lib/apt/lists directory:`.
try with combination of these two commands:

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

and then

`sudo apt-get update`

this should work.

Comment: Solved my problem like a charm!! but can you provide an explanation as to why this will happen